# display product model in category page opencart

Tags: opencart

I am trying to show the product model in the category page.
I have added 
`'model'=> $result['model']`
in the /catalog/controller/product/category.php

```
$data['products'][] = array(

                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],

                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
                    'model'       => $result['model']
                );
```

also i have edited category.tpl with the following code in the products foreach

```
<?php if (!empty($product['model'])) { ?>
                    <h5 class="model">&nbsp;<?php echo $product['model']; ?></h5>
                <?php } ?>
```

but nothing shows in the category page.

What else should i do?

Comment: Try setting 'model' to static text to test that the .tpl file is at least able to display it correctly

Comment: I replaced price,name and in both cases i got undefined index error

Comment: Agis Soleas, Try to print_r($results) in category.php file and check it give result of model or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the sql query includes the model field. Many times the queries are specific and does not return all the fields within the database table.
To do this navigate to `catalog > model > catalog > product.php` and look for the function `getProducts` 
 Edit this function to allow for the model.